# Advice on which test to run to show a valid sample of participants

Tags: sample

I have collected data on medical diagnosis and am wanting to know which test I should use to show my participants are similar to a pre and post intervention.  The first set of data yielded 53% male and the post data yielded a 55% male.  I used and independent variable T-Test.  I am not sure this is the best test to use, is there any other test I should run to show validity? 
Yes, I collected data on 2 separate groups of patients admitted with a specific diagnosis in a 3 month time frame from Jan-Mar, then a new intervention was put into place to improve the outcome of patients with this diagnosis which went into place in April. So after a 1 month adaptation period I collected data from a different group based on that same diagnosis from May-July. Basically I just want to show the 2 groups were similar in age and gender.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the expression "*show my participants are similar to a pre and post intervention*". What did you test in your t-test? Generally with pre-and-post situations you're talking about the same group of people, in which case the percentage that are male shouldn't be changing. Can you clarify your question with specific details of what you have and what, exactly, you did?

Comment: Yes, I collected data on patients admitted with a specific diagnosis a 3 month time from from Jan-Mar, then a new intervention was put into place to improve the outcome of patients with this diagnosis which went into place in April.  So after a 1 month adaptation period I collected data again based on that same diagnosis from May-July.  Basically I just want to show the 2 groups were similar in age and sex, if that helps?

Comment: No, sorry the exact details of your design are still not sufficiently clear. It sounds like two different groups of patients but the mention of pre- and post- would suggest the same patients were tested twice. Can you move the additional details you gave in the previous comment up to your question, so that readers don't have to read the comments to get the details, and then specifically describe the circumstances surrounding the two sets of measurements to make it crystal clear whether or not there are any patients in common between the two. That is, clearly describe *who* was measured *when*.

Comment: However, I will say that if you want to compare proportions, it generally shouldn't be with a t-test.

Comment: I added to the question, yes it is 2 different groups.

Answer (score 0):

A test of equality of proportions would be a two sample proportions test, or a chi-square test. For ages (as long as they're not really coarsely grouped), a test of equality of means would be a t-test; an example of a test of equality of distribution would be the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

However, an ordinary hypothesis test is not an appropriate way to "show the groups are similar".

In large samples very similar groups would be rejected as being the same, while in small samples very different groups would not be rejected.

Better to specify what you mean by "similar" and make some assessment of that.

One possibility would be equivalence testing, but a reasonable measure of how different the two samples are is probably adequate - diagnostic plots or basic statistical comparisons.